# Conditional SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a SQL query I need to make conditional, here is my SQL query as it stands currently:

```
-- IF the video count is 1
    UPDATE tbl_Video SET
    [Featured] = 1
    WHERE [VideoId] = 1
    GO
-- ELSE IF Video Count is greater than 1
    UPDATE tbl_Video SET
    [Featured] = 0
    WHERE [Featured] = 1
    GO
    -- Set the top 5 viewed videos as featured as default
    UPDATE tbl_Video SET
    [Featured] = 1
    WHERE VideoId In (SELECT TOP 5 VideoId FROM tbl_Video
    ORDER BY Views DESC)
    GO
-- END
```

Hopefully the comments in the query above will explain what I am trying to achieve, the scenario is:

> *If the video count is 1, make the featured column true where video Id = 1.
>
>   If the video count is greater than 1, mark all the featured columns as false then make the top 5 viewed videos as featured.*

Database is SQL Server.

Thanks,

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL sorry, I have edited my question to state this now. Thanks.

Comment: just guessing but  - do you definitely want `SELECT TOP 5 VideoId FROM tbl_Video ORDER BY Views DESC` and not something like `SELECT TOP 5 y.VideoId FROM #tbl_Video y GROUP BY y.VideoId ORDER BY SUM(y.[Views]) DESC` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in an sql server procedure you could do:

```
declare @videoCount integer

--this is just a guess at what video count is
select @videoCount = count(*) from tbl_video

if (@videoCount = 1)
    UPDATE tbl_Video SET
    [Featured] = 1
    WHERE [VideoId] = 1
ELSE IF (@videoCount > 1)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_Video SET
    [Featured] = 0
    WHERE [Featured] = 1

    UPDATE tbl_Video SET
    [Featured] = 1
    WHERE VideoId In (SELECT TOP 5 VideoId FROM tbl_Video ORDER BY Views DESC)
END
```

Answer (score 1):

if you already have `@videoCount` variable which is `not null`

```
--Using case
update tbl_Video SET
    [Featured] = case when @videoCount = 1 then 0 
                      when @videoCount > 0 end --else [Featured] end
where [VideoId] = 1

--Using cte
;with cte as 
(
    select top (5) * 
    from tbl_Video
    order by Views desc
)
update cte set [Featured] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @VideoCount INT

SELECT @VideoCount = COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Video

IF @VideoCount = 1
BEGIN
   UPDATE tbl_Video SET
   [Featured] = 1
    WHERE [VideoId] = 1
   GO
END
ELSE IF @VideoCount > 1
BEGIN
   UPDATE tbl_Video SET
   [Featured] = 0
   WHERE [Featured] = 1
   GO
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do that in one query:

```
update  tv
set     Featured = case when rn <= 5 then 1 else 0 end
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by ViewCount desc) as rn
        ,       *
        from    tbl_Video
        ) tv
```

If there's only one video, it must be in the top 5 viewed video's, so no need for a special case.

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75f94/2/0)